# Multiple Headers in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, compression, deflate

I'm running code that seems to hit the "AppendHeader" twice in the code.

```
Response.Filter = New DeflateStream(Response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress, True)
Response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate")
```

...

```
Response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate")
```

I have tried using the following....

```
Response.Headers("Content-encoding") = "deflate"
```

But it says

```
This operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.
```

How do I check for a headers existence, and overwrite it rather than appending it.

Comment: how did you checked that headers existence? Fiddler?

Comment: You were correct, the hear existed, but was faulty Content-Encoding: deflate, deflate

Comment: Fiddler rocks for debugging HTTP.

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
if (!(Response.Headers["Content-encoding"] ?? "").Contains("deflate"))
{
    Response.AddHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about running your app in IIS Integrated Mode?  It's a setting on the AppPool in IIS Manager.

Also, you can use Fiddler to help debug the headers.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize `Response.AppendHeader` & `Response.Headers["Content-encoding"]` won't work with IIS6